Cannot make changes to attributes when Qt Designer UI is launched by identify feature
I have created a QGIS form for a layer using qt designer.  When I open the layer's attribute table I can edit and save changes to attributes through this form without issue.  When the form pops up as a result of picking a feature in the layer using identify feature, I can toggle the layer into edit mode, but changes made through the form do not seem to be passed back to the table. Save layer edits is never activated. When I toggle the layer out of edit mode, the changes are reverted in the form without prompting to save.
When I remove the custom form, the system form works as expected: attributes can be changed and saved or cancelled.

What version of QGIS are you using? (Can you edit it into the question?)

When creating forms, the buttons have meaning to the system.  In this case, replacing the close button with a save button and a cancel button made the UI work as expected.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
